# ajax auto complete extender results as strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, autocomplete

i have run into an interesting issue...
i am using ASP and auto-complete extender on a textbox
i got everything working but i was getting very odd results.

when searching for something like `315122-111` the only result that would come up was `315011`.
this is because the item-number is being treated like a number instead of a string

`315122-111=315011`

i am sending everything as a string.. when i use fiddler to view the traffic all the auto-complete responses coming in `315122-111`  they are just not being properly...

any ideas on how to fix this dilemma?

Comment: very interesting problem.  Am I understanding correctly that fiddler is showing you that the string "315122-111" is indeed being sent to the server as it should be?  If this is the case then we need to look at your service that you have set in your AutoComplete extender.  Have you tried putting a breakpoint or logging the incoming value on your processing method?

Comment: yes all items look fine until the autocomplete extender does its magic!

Answer (score 0):

Is there an eval() being called on the javascript side?

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp

There's a bug that was fixed in this post:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1164200.aspx?New+AutoCompleteExtender+doesn+t+work+with+Numeric+Values

They stated:

```
 1. download the ajax control toolkit source. open the file
 2. AjaxControlToolkit\AutoComplete\AutoCompleteBehavior.js at line 748,
 3. you should see: "if (String.isInstanceOfType(pair)) {"

That line is what is causing the problem.... to fix it, I changed that line to  "if (String.isInstanceOfType(pair) || Int.isInstanceOfType(pair)) {".
```

Comment: i am using the ajaxControlToolkit Library so i do not know what is going on in the JavaScript because it is being auto generated